# How to find out what is using swap on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, swap, process-management

I'm trying to pinpoint what process(es) is eating swap on my FreeBSD server.

I can only see how much is being used (top) but not what process is swapping its guts out.

I tried searching Google for this but didn't find anything.

Is there a way to display list of swapped data by process natively or by using some external software to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

FreeBSD's `ps` command prints a `W` in the `state` column to indicate that a process is swapped out. By default, `ps` prints `state` as the third column, so this will give you what you want:

```
$ ps ax | awk 'NR==1{print};$3 ~ /W/'
```

`'NR==1{print}'` will give you the column headers. Omit it if you don't need or want them.

Note also that FreeBSD's `top` displays swapped out processes with their name (the final column) surrounded by angle brackets.

Comment: What does “the process is swapped out” mean? Swapped out isn't a binary thing when it comes to a process. Each individual memory page that belongs to the process may or may not be in swap.

Comment: I have been thinking about this, too, @Gilles, but what the @D_Bye wrote above is consistent with the docs. See manpage for `ps` and extended status `W`.

Comment: In this case, that all of a process's pages are paged out. Turns out it's pretty hard to find processes that are only partially paged out...